# Selenium JavaScript Clicking in a Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, browser, automation

The below code goes to a page, finds the dropdown menu and clicks the first one in the list. How do I adjust the following code to be able to select the second or third item in the list?

```
await browser
       .findElement(By.css('#historyTabDropdown ul>li>a'))
       .then(e => e.click());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using css selector nth-child.
The css is li:nth-child(2)

```
await browser
       .findElement(By.css('#historyTabDropdown ul>li:nth-child(2)>a'))
       .then(e => e.click());
```